# Rails 3.1: Devise_invitable requires Rails 3.0.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

When adding `devise_invitable` to my `Gemfile`, I get this error when doing `bundle install`.

```
$ bundle install
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    devise_invitable (~> 0.4.0) depends on
      rails (~> 3.0.0)

    rails (3.1.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Gemfile`, update `devise_invitable` to use a newer version (current is 0.5.4) instead of 0.4.0; 0.5.4 supports Rails 3.1.

Comment: Or if you have not specified any version for devise in your Gemfile, just do a `bundle update devise`